# Nft data from marketplaces

Tags: nft

How can I get the addresses who’ve interacted with an NFT contract? Need this to generate contract analytics / Renat Ghoste

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are simpler solution but I think you could implement something like that using the [moralis api](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-all-transfers-of-an-nft-collection)  for instance.

Get the transactions of the nft collection and do some analytics with that.